# Need to find the number of contents in the array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a char array and I want to find out the number of contents in it.
For example, my array is:

```
char myArray[10];
```

And after input it's content is:

```
ABC
```

Now I want to store in a variable 'size', the size of the area related to content. So, in this case:

```
size = 3
```

How do I find that?

Comment: Sounds like you want `std::string` or `std::vector` and their `size()` function.

Answer (score 3):

A naive way of doing this would be to look for the null-terminating character `\0`, this is already implemented for you in the C-function `strlen`, so there are two ways of doing this:

```
int StringLength( const char* str, int maxLength )
{
     for( int i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i )
     {
          if( str[i] == '\0' )
              return i;
     }

     return -1;
}
```

Or you could just call [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) as follows:

```
int iLength = strlen( myArray );
```

However, as you have tagged this [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), the best way to do this would be to not deal with C-style character arrays and instead use the extremely useful [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen(myArray)` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

int len = strlen(myArray).

strlen is a part of stdlib.h library. Don't forget to declare it in your program.

Comment: C++ => `<cstdlib>` and `std::strlen()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

defining array as `char myArray[10];` will not always initialize it's content to zeros, so depending on how you fill it with ABC you either can or cannot find the corect lenght. In worst case regular strlen() will always report  numbers >10, or even result in read access vialation. I try initialize it like `char myArray[10] = {};` first